# ReactJS: How to change placeholder font size of Material Ui Autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I want to change the placeholder fontsize of Material Ui Autocomplet. Is there any way?

[image]

```
             <Autocomplete
                  multiple
                  id="tags-outlined"
                  options={top100Films}
                  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
                  defaultValue={[top100Films[13]]}
                  filterSelectedOptions
                  size="small"

                  renderInput={(params) => (
                    <TextField
                      {...params}
                     
                      variant="outlined"

                      placeholder="Enter Transshipment Ports"

                      
                    />
                  )}
                />
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your example, you can target the `input` element of the component you render in `renderInput` which is `TextField` using `makeStyles`

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  customTextField: {
    "& input::placeholder": {
      fontSize: "20px"
    }
  }
})

<TextField
  classes={{ root: classes.customTextField }}
  {...params}
  variant="outlined"
  placeholder="Enter Transshipment Ports"
/>
```

Example below using forked MUI demo

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

Comment: Also works:
```input: {
 "&::placeholder": {
    color: "red",
  },
},```

Answer (score 2):

The sx property allows users to override the styling applied to the MuiFormLabel-root object, including the font size. This is useful for creating custom labels that better suit the user's design needs.

```
<TextField
        {...props}
        sx={{
          '& .MuiFormLabel-root': {
            fontSize: '0.8rem',
          },
        }}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the ::placeholder css to the class/id of the input field, and change the font-size

Example:

```
#tags-outlined::placeholder {
   font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: I did, just add the line of code that i sent you to your css, and let me know